# I have a ceiling fan light combo

Tags: ceiling-fan

There are two black wires on pull chain four white and four black on the light assembly I had to change pull switch a d wires pull off from the ceiling fan there is two white wires a black wire and a blue wire can anyone help figure out the wiring??

Comment: not from that description alone.

Comment: The two white are likely neutral.  Black is typically for the fan motor, and blue is for the light kit.  It's really unclear what you're asking, as you haven't described your situation very well.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. As the  others have noted, you need to  give us more information (a picture? a diagram?) before we can help you.